# How to clear ui-select programmatically?

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I would like to find a way to clear the selection of a ui-select by code.

For example I have the following code

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedCustomerCode" ng-if="CustomerIds.length>1" on-select="CustomerCodeFiltersOnSelectCallback($item, $model)" theme="bootstrap">
  <ui-select-match class="ui-select-match" allow-clear="true" placeholder="Επιλογή κωδικού πελάτη...">{{$select.selected.CCode}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices class="ui-select-choices" repeat="customer in CustomerIds | propsFilter: {CCode: $select.search}">
    <div ng-bind-html="customer.CCode | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

I want to clink on a clear button and clear some inputs including the ui-select.
What is the code in order to clear ui-select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should clear `cont.selectedCustomerCode` variable:

```
<button ng-click="cont.selectedCustomerCode = ''">clear</button>
```

**Edit:**

You should consider exposing you attributes on a variable. That's the recommended way.

Comment: This makes sense but I have already tried it and didn't work.
The weird thing is that I put a 
<div>{{selectedCustomerCode}}</div>
in my html and it shows nothing before or after any selection of the ui-select

Comment: @vagelis i made an edit. Can you try my suggestion and tell me if it works?

Answer (score 7):

The problem has been solved.
I don't know why, but having only `selectedCustomerCode` in ng-model did not work properly.
I assigned the `selectedCustomerCode` as an object:

```
ng-model="selectedCustomer.selectedCustomerCode"
```

then I was able to clear it like this:

```
selectedCustomer.selectedCustomerCode = ''
```

If I had

```
ng-model="selectedCustomerCode"
```

then reassigning it to:

```
selectedCustomerCode = ''
```

somehow does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option allow-clear for ui-select-match that does the thing for you, you will have the x on the right and you can clear it by clicking it. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-match

```
<ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="Select or search in a list...">
  <span>{{$select.selected.name}}</span>
</ui-select-match>
```

working example http://plnkr.co/edit/DbbUE68QlNLjx97pBZ56?p=preview

Comment: that could be a solution but I would like to do it by code from another button that clears all the html inputs that I have in the form.

Comment: then on button click clear the ng-model .like $scope.selectedCustomerCode='' or {} or [] . whatever it is

Comment: I have tried all of them but nothing seems to work.
The weird thing is that I put a 
<div>{{selectedCustomerCode}}</div>
in my html and it shows nothing before or after any selection of the ui-select

Comment: then there is a only option is there

Comment: first create a global object like :$scope.form={}; then define ng-model of each control like form.control1 or control 2 in the last on button click pass this on button click like ng-click="click(form)" . and in your controller make it empty . it will definitely work for u

Comment: and also declare the object at the starting of controller code like

Comment: $scope.form={control1NgModelName:""or {}, control2NgModelName:"" or {} and so on}

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that I used today is to create an empty state by adding a clear element to the list repeated in the ui-select-choices

```
vm.CustomerIds.unshift({"CCode":"Select..."});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in cases when in general you want ui-select cleared is to declare ng-model on your ui-select for example as:

```
ng-model="selectedCustomerCode.code"
```

and in your controlller you wold initialize object as:

```
$scope.selectedCustomerCode = {};
```

and whenever later in code you need this property cleared you would simply reinitialize it as follows:

```
$scope.selectedCustomerCode = {};
```